# LLVM get constant integer back from Value*

Tags: c++, llvm

I create a llvm::Value* from a integer constant like this:

```
llvm::Value* constValue = llvm::ConstantInt::get( llvmContext , llvm::APInt( node->someInt() ));
```

now i want to retrieve the compile-time constant value back;

```
int constIntValue = constValue->???
```

The examples shown in [LLVM Programmer manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa) seem to imply that cast<> will accept a pointer when using the type (rather than the type plus pointer) template parameter, however i'm pretty sure thats failing as from 2.8:

```
llvm::Value* foo = 0;
llvm::ConstantInt* intValue = & llvm::cast< llvm::ConstantInt , llvm::Value >(foo );

//build error:
//error: no matching function for call to ‘cast(llvm::Value*&)’
```

What would be the correct approach here?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Given `llvm::Value* foo` and you know that `foo` is actually a `ConstantInt`, I believe that the idiomatic LLVM code approach is to use `dyn_cast` as follows:

```
if (llvm::ConstantInt* CI = dyn_cast<llvm::ConstantInt>(foo)) {
  // foo indeed is a ConstantInt, we can use CI here
}
else {
  // foo was not actually a ConstantInt
}
```

If you're absolutely *sure* that `foo` is a `ConstantInt` and are ready to be hit with an assertion failure if it isn't, you can use `cast` instead of `dyn_cast`.

---

P.S. Do note that `cast` and `dyn_cast` are part of LLVM's own implementation of RTTI. `dyn_cast` acts somewhat similarly to the standard C++ `dynamic_cast`, though there are differences in implementation and performance (as can be [read here](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa)).

Comment: According to the link you provide, if the pointer is not pointing to the expected type, it's `cast` that will lead to an assertion failure, and `dyn_cast` will return 0, instead of the opposite.

Comment: How to detect whether this ConstantInt is signed or unsigned ?

Answer (score 47):

Eli's answer is great, but it's missing the final part, which is getting the integer back. The full picture should look like this:

```
if (ConstantInt* CI = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(Val)) {
  if (CI->getBitWidth() <= 32) {
    constIntValue = CI->getSExtValue();
  }
}
```

Of course, you can also change it to `<= 64` if `constIntValue` is a 64-bit integer, etc.

And as Eli wrote, if you are confident the value is indeed of type `ConstInt`, you can use `cast<ConstantInt>` instead of `dyn_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers work if the constant is a variable in current file.

However if the constant variable is a global variable defined in other file, which is refered by current file by extern. In this case the variable in current file is a `PointerType` value. We have to get its real value through following code:

```
Constant *c;

if (isa<GlobalValue>(c)) {
        GlobalValue *gvalue = dyn_cast<GlobalValue>(c);
        GlobalVariable *gv = dyn_cast<GlobalVariable>(gvalue);
        ConstantInt *ci = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(gv->getInitializer());
        errs() << ci->getValue();
}
```