# How to get the exact integer from a Value

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a Value* type named `indexValue`, and the type is i32.
I think `indexValue` must hold a number which type is int.
Now I want to use the exact number which pointed by indexValue , 
so I do like this:

```
ConstantInt* CI = llvm::cast<llvm::ConstantInt>(indexValue); //This is wrong, so is dyn_cast.

uint64_t index = indexValue->getZExtValue();

uint64_t size = index + 1;
```

I don't know if it is the right way.
So, could anybody tell the way to get the integer content from a Value* which type is i32?

I'll be very very grateful if there is any answer.

Comment: These are [`llvm::ConstantInt`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html) and [`llvm::Value`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html). Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you outline is more or less correct - there's also a more complete answer in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315176/llvm-get-constant-integer-back-from-value). But that is of course assuming the value is a `ConstantInt`.

If you expect some value to be a constant but it isn't, you should make sure you're running one of the [constant propagation passes](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html) first. If the value is still not a constant there's nothing much you can do, except for maybe writing your own specialized constant propagation pass...

Comment: You are right, I am not sure that the Value is Constant, so I think my way to deal with this is not correct. I will think about another way. Thanks a lot