# Reading variable pointed by a pointer in llvm

Tags: llvm

Pointer type can be deduced through:

```
Value* v= i->getOperand(0);
.......    
if(PointerType* pt=dyn_cast<PointerType>(v->getType())){
      pt->getElementType()->getTypeID();
```

How can I read the value that this pointer points to?

I is a CallInst.

Comment: You read the content of memory with a `load` instruction, but I have a feeling that's not the answer you're looking for. Could you clarify what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Oak: I have a function that takes two input paramerters. I want to read the values that I pass to this function: e.g. Foo(int i, int j). Void main(){foo(6,7)}... I want to read 6 and 7.... Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Given a `CallInst`, you can get an argument via `getArgOperand()` or iterate over all of them with `arg_operands()`. The arguments you get this way are just `Value`s, and you can do anything you can do with other `Value`s on them.

In particular, if those `Value`s are constants, you can get the actual values used in the compiler - see this related stackoverflow question: [LLVM get constant integer back from Value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315176/llvm-get-constant-integer-back-from-value)

Comment: The problem i'm facing is how to read from value that is pointed by a pointer value. Thanks :)

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer then isn't this really unrelated to the fact that you're dealing with a `CallInst`? Shouldn't the question just be "how to get a value from a pointer?"

Comment: I thought there is a way to extract it from a call instruction.

Comment: I guess, I'll have to extract it from a store instruction.