# llvm::VectorType with size from runtime constant

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

## Problem

I am trying to create a vector type in LLVM (version 12) to exploit the SIMD feature associated with this type. However, the required size of the array is stored in an integer variable. The desired LLVM IR code could possibly look like,

```
;; Pseudo-code for the desired LLVM IR
%0 = load i64, i64* %a
%vec = alloca <%0 x double>, align 16
```

Generating such IR code seems to be impossible though.
It is possible to generate vector alloca with compile-time constants, e.g. a vector of size 4 could be generated as

```
%vec = alloca <4 x double>, align 16
```

using the LLVM C++ API as

```cpp
llvm::Type* I = llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(TheContext);
auto arr_type = llvm::VectorType::get(I,4,false); 
llvm::AllocaInst* arr_alloc = Builder.CreateAlloca(arr_type, 0 , "vec" );
```

however using a runtime constant obtained from a variable seems to be a problem, since the llvm::VectorType::get interface only allows the size to be specified as an unsigned int. I.e. the available interface looks like

```cpp
static VectorType* llvm::VectorType::get    (   Type *  ElementType,
unsigned    NumElements,
bool    Scalable 
)
```

However, if I load the variable value from %a and I **cant** create a vector type from it using,

```cpp
llvm::Value *SIZE = Builder.CreateLoad(IntType,Address_Of_Variable_A,"a");
auto arr_type = llvm::VectorType::get(I,SIZE,false); // this line fails to compile (since SIZE is not an unsigned int)
```

I also could not typecast the Value* pointer to a llvm::ConstantInt* pointer to get the integer value back from the Value* as done in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5315581/2940917 .
This happens due to the fact that SIZE is in this case a LoadInst* as opposed to being created from a ConstantInt::get as done in the linked question.

Is there a way to achieve this? This seems like an essential operation for many cases. It would be surprising if there is no way to declare a vector size from the runtime constant.

Could someone point me to the right information source/idea?

Comment: The storage for instances of a type is generally allocated it used at compile time, e.g. "instances of this fit in a cpu register" or "sizeof that is 42". Compilers would often benefit from knowing at compile time something that is only known at runtime. There's a workaround for arrays (use a zero-sized type and index beyond the end) but I suspect that won't work all that well for vectors, at least not they're [used for SIMD operations](https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html).

Comment: Thanks @arnt . Another problem I suspected with using a zero-sized type and indexing beyond the end was: "How do you keep track of the size of the array, i.e., what indices are valid and how does one ensure that the memory locations used for the array don't overlap with some other data location, causing data to get overwritten?"

Comment: Another thing I could do is declare an alloca of type "double" but with an array size of the loaded value. The CreateAlloca interface in the LLVM API allows for this. I.e. I can create a valid IR of the form "%vec = alloca double, i64 %a" where %a is the loaded value for the array size. I'm not sure how to get the SIMD operation working for such an alloca though.

Comment: I think you're going to be stuck with generating N versions of the IR, one for each size of simd vector you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, Flexo. I was thinking of running a "for" loop creating an array of vectors of fixed sizes such that each fixed-size vector represents a subvector of the desired vector of size given by the run time constant. Wasn't sure if this is the right way to do this, or if there is something better out there already?

Comment: I was also looking into scalable vectors in llvm and using llvm.vscale intrinsic to create scaled vectors of the desired size. But vscale seems to be a constant throughout the execution. So wasn't sure if this can be used to create different sizes of vectors by changing the value of vscale before every new vector of a different size being declared. Has anyone looked into this?